# Do not display information from the controller on jsp jstl

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i have problem with display data on jsp page from using jstl.

This is my page, and displayed information:

```
EMPTY !!!
Name    Email   Action
```

**get-user.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>All users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:if test="${empty webModels}">
            <h3>EMPTY !!!</h3>
        </c:if>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${webModels}" var="web">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${web.userName}</td>
                        <td>${web.userEmail}</td>
                        <td>${web.Action}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**controller** print information size **4**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<WebModel> getWebModels(){
    List<WebModel> webModels = serviceWeb.getAllUser();
    System.out.println(webModels.size()); //not empty
    return webModels;
}
```

**WebModel** i getting data from database from a few table and main data i set in WebModel

```
public class WebModel {
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    private String Action;
    //getter setter constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation about return types of controller methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types) says:

> Any other return type is considered to be a single model attribute to be exposed to the view, using the attribute name specified through `@ModelAttribute` at the method level (or the default attribute name based on the return type class name). The model is implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of `@ModelAttribute` annotated reference data accessor methods.

So, if I read it correctly, you should use `list` instead of `webModels` in your JSP, or you should annotate the method with

```
@ModelAttribute("webModels")
```

Comment: Thank, I'm added `@ModelAttribute("webModels")` and this working!